# Can my html pages be integrated with wiki?

Tags: html, wiki, screwturn

I have deployed my HTML pages with tables and other varying contents, 
if the content in my page is to be changed and published timely, what is to be done? Can wiki be integrated with HTML pages?

Comment: To which wiki software do you refer?

Comment: I am not sure about it, but my requirement is Screwturn wiki...